# sql oracle case 'from keyword not found where expected'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select an existing column and creating another one using the code indented, but I'm getting alternatively the 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected' error or the 'missing keyword' error.
(I'm a beginner)

Can you please help me out?

Edit: id is an integer, description is a string
I want to create a column for each id that will serve as a flag when the description value is matching 'VALUE1' or 'VALUE2'. In table 1 there is simply the mapping from the identifier of the values to the string, on table 2 I have all the records.

```
select id as ID, 

    'cast( select description from db.table_1 
    join db.table_2 on table_2.id = table_1.id
    case when (table_1.description in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')) then '1'
    else '0' 
    end
    ) as boolean' as DesiredColumnName,

from db.table_2
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You code has multiple errors, no matter how one attempts to fix it.  The specific problem causing this error is the comma before the `from`, but removing it really won't fix the query.

Comment: What do you need to do?

Comment: Oracle does not have the `BOOLEAN` data type. So, besides all the syntactical problems, after you fix them all you will run into this as an issue, and you won't be able to fix it as easily. You will need to decide if the `DesiredColumnName` (are you really sure that is a good column name for what you store there?) so - you will need to decide if you want that column to be `NUMBER(1)` data type, allowed (through a check constraint) to only hold the values `0` and `1`, or to be `CHAR(1)` with only the values `'T'` and `'F'`, or perhaps `'Y'` and `'N'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
select t2.id, decode(t1.description, 'VALUE1', 1, 'VALUE2', 1 ,0) as DesiredColumnName 
 from db.table2 t2 inner join db.table1 t1 on (t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: The second script I would also vote for. Most logical.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to speculate on what you actually want to do:

```
select t2.id,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table_1 t1
                          where t1.description in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2') and
                                t2.id = t1.id   
                         )
             then 1 else 0
       end) as DesiredColumnName,
from db.table_2 t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma ',' before from.

select id as ID,

```
'cast( select description from db.table_1 
join db.table_2 on table_2.id = table_1.id
case when (table_1.description in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')) then '1'
else '0' 
end
) as boolean' as DesiredColumnName
```

from db.table_2